# Can I write control characters to someone else's terminal?

Tags: aix, terminal-emulator

A lot of people log into the same AIX 6.1 server as I do with a terminal emulator that automatically interprets and runs code encapsulated by certain control characters as VBA script instead of writing it to the display. So as a prank, I have a file that contains a sequence of characters that displays a message in a popup box that I want to write to their terminals.

```
$ cat msgbox.txt  
*message box pops up*
```

But when I write it to someone, the effect is lost:

`$ cat msgbox.txt | write *my other sesssion*`

On the other session:
`Message from *myself* [*datetime*] \o 33 *code to show a msgbox* \o 33\<EOT>`

Where the "\o 33" replaces ASCII character 27. Is it possible to send control characters through write, or do I need to do something different?

Comment: You also need to wear gauntlets to defend against those of us who will break your fingers afterward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know specifically about AIX, but on most unices, you cannot do this, by design. You can't read or write on other people's terminals, what happens there is none of your business. The `write` program has [extra privileges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (setuid root, or setgid `tty`, depending on the system). It takes care to sanitize the input you throw at it so as not to disrupt the other person too much.

If you really want to send control characters to a user's terminal, you need to be root.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `cat` it directly to the `tty`/`pty` device they're using.  You would also need to make sure their terminal does the same thing yours does with the characters; you might need to watch out for the tty mode (beware of newline expansion).

Comment: I don't have permissions to do that. That is why I need to use some program like `write`.

Comment: You do, actually; if `write` works, `cat` to the correct device node will.  `write` just automates finding the device node from `utmp`, sanitizes, and adds a header.

Comment: When I try to cat to the device, I get `"bash: /dev/pts/3: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action."` But when I write, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @geekosaur, on my system, `write` is [setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setgid) `tty`, so it's not necessarily true that if `write` works it means you have permissions to use `cat`.  (Although my system is Linux; I don't know about AIX's `write`.)